# Uniqueness constraint on multiple columns causes issue with null values

Tags: oracle

According to oracle docs, a null cannot be equal or unequal to any value or to another null

This is evident in case of a uniqueness constraint on any column. But the behaviour is different if the uniqueness constraint in on multiple columns. eg:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    col1 NUMBER(2),
    col2 NUMBER(2),
    CONSTRAINT uniq_col1_col2 UNIQUE (col1, col2)
);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, NULL);
# ORA-00001: unique constraint (XYZ.UNIQ_COL1_COL2) violated
```

Why is this so? And how can I specify the constraint to ignore nulls?

**EDIT**

More specifically, if rows `(null), (null)` are unique, why are `(1,null), (1,null)` not unique? What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: So if it ignored nulls 1=1 and it would violate constraint right?  (it already is ignoring the nulls)  the equal and not equal is in reference to `=` and `<>.`   `is not null` or `is null` are null safe operations and can compare against null.  so is null is being compared to is null for col2 thus they are equal so is 1 = 1 since all data matches (duplicate)

Comment: What do you actually want to happen? That both of those inserts would be allowed, but two inserts with the same `col1` and the same non-null `col2` would not? How would you distinguish between those two rows with `col1 = 1`?

Answer (score 5):

That's what [the documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52195) (emphasis added):

> To satisfy a unique constraint, no two rows in the table can have the same value for the unique key. However, the unique key made up of a single column can contain nulls. To satisfy a composite unique key, no two rows in the table or view can have the same combination of values in the key columns. Any row that contains nulls in all key columns automatically satisfies the constraint. **However, two rows that contain nulls for one or more key columns and the same combination of values for the other key columns violate the constraint.**

It's doing what it's supposed to do. With your two sample inserts, both (potential) rows contain null in one key column and the same value (1) in the other key column, so the constraint is violated.

Nothing else would really make sense; allowing both inserts to go ahead would leave you with two indistinguishable rows, in key terms anyway.

---

You asked:

> More specifically, if rows `(null), (null)` are unique, why are `(1,null), (1,null)` not unique? What is the rationale behind this?

Because there is no other key column to enforce uniqueness.

As you said, null isn't equal to or not equal to anything. If your unique key was only on `col1` and you had two rows with it set to null, which is allowed, then querying `where col1 is null` would find both - which is OK because `is null` isn't about equality. You can say that both rows matched the condition, but not that they are equal to null. With your two-column key the equivalent would be `where col1 = 1 and col2 is null`. Now equality *does* come into play.

In both cases the nulls are ignored, and whatever is left still has to be unique. With a single-column key there is nothing else to enforce uniqueness. With the two-column key if `col2` is null then `col1` is still there to be compared, and that on its own has to be unique, effectively.

You're also allowed to do:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (null, null);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (null, null);
```

The same thing applies; they nulls are effectively ignored, but now - as with the single-column-key - there is nothing left to enforce uniqueness against.

Comment: I understand that it's doing what it's supposed to do. Im trying to understand the rationale behind this behaviour. Updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a constraint that ignores nulls and only prevents insert of complete duplicate keys then you can use a function-based unique index that only holds keys that are totally non-null:

```
create unique index uniq_col1_col2 on table1
  ( case when col1 is not null and col2 is not null then col1 end
  , case when col1 is not null and col2 is not null then col2 end
  );
```